# Pattern matching on function parameters in Python

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, pattern-matching, parameter-passing

Suppose I have a function named `generator` that returns a 4-tuple with randomly selected values in certain pre-specified ranges. Let's say the tuple is of the form `(age, sex, location, marital_status)`:

```
age is in range(5, 85)
sex is a member of the set {"m", "f"}
location is a member of the set of all the cities in California
marital_status is a member of {"married", "single", "separated"}
```

On the other hand, let's say I have defined 20 different functions with definitions like this:

```
def p1 (age, sex, location, marital_status)
def p2 (age, sex, location, marital_status)   
.
.
```

where `p1` is supposed to receive parameters with values of the following form:

```
`age` must be in the range 20 to 45
`sex` must be male
`location` could be any city in Southern California
`marital_status` could be either single or married
```

and imagine a different set of values for `p2` all the way to `p20`.

What is a pragmatic way to determine which set of generated values match which function?

In this case all the definitions where exactly the same, but I can imagine instances where there might be slight differences in the definitions, for example `p18` could be `def p1 (age, location)` with specific limitations on the range of possibilities for `age` and `location`.

P.S. The patters are not necessarily mutually exclusive, meaning a set of generated values might as well match more than one function.

Comment: Since you are on Python 3, *Function annotations* might be the way to go: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/.

Comment: Are the patterns mutually exclusive, or is it possible that more patterns match?

Comment: @dlask: Good point. There is a slight possibility that the pattern matches more than one function.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to loop on p1-p20, check in the functions themselves, throw a ValueError if no match to reqs and just move on to next function?  Avoids code duplication.

Comment: @JLPeyret: Sounds interesting. Could you please elaborate in an answer?

Comment: Can you explain that whats the relation between `generator` function and `p1,p2,...`

Comment: @Kasramvd The `generator` function "generates" a 4-tuple with random values. Those values could only trigger certain functions given their constraints. The question is, how?

Comment: Yes and that's exactly what I just said and also explained in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a Pythonic way in Python 3.X (but not 2.X), you can attach [*annotation information*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#accessing-function-annotations) (arbitrary user-defined data about a function’s arguments and result) to a function object. Here you can use this feature in a decorator to wrap your function to check the range of your arguments.

For example you can use the following range test function :

```
def rangetest(func):
    def onCall(**kargs):
        argchecks = func.__annotations__

        if all(val in range(*argchecks.get(arg)) for arg,val in kargs.items()):
            return func(**kargs)
        else :
              print ("invalid arg range")
    return onCall


@rangetest
def func(a:(1, 5), b:(4,7), c:(0, 10)):
    print(a + b + c)
```

Demo :

```
func(a=2, b=6, c=8)
16
func(a=2, b=6, c=15)
invalid arg range
```

There is some point here. The first is that, since the annotation information is within a dictionary (python returns it as a dictionary) and dictionaries don't have a specific order, you need to use keyword arguments in your function to be able to get its relative range in annotation information dictionary.

Also here I just used numeric range but you can use some custom ranges like list of words like what you show in your question.But inside the `all` you need to check its type then based on its type use a proper operation :

```
all(kwargs.get(arg) in range(*arg_range) if is instance (arg_range,tuple) else kwargs.get(arg) in arg_range for arg,arg_range in argchecks.items())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# define test t1 for function p1
def t1(params):
    return params["age"] in range(5, 85) \
        and params["sex"] in ["m", "f"] \
        and cityof(params["location"], "California") \
        and params["marital_status"] in ["married", "single", "separated"]
# and similarly for other p* functions

# define functions
def p1(params): ...
def p2(params): ...
# and so on

# bind tests and functions
RULES = {
    (t1, p1),
    (t2, p2),
    ...
}

# have the right functions called
def go(params):
    for rule in RULES:
        if rule[0](params):
            rule[1](params)

# test it
go({"age": 6, "sex": "m", "location": "somewhere", "marital_status": "single"})
```

Just a few comments:

- The tests can be included in the functions themselves.
- The test functions have to cope with missing parameters too.
- It's also possible to use function parameters directly.

There are actually several variations possible but the main principle is the same:
*Find the matching function and call it*.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to add formatted doc strings to your functions (instead of type checking each argument), then you can consider doing something like this:

```
# This function has a foratted doc string.
# :argument: Truth condition to be evaluated
# If any condition is False, function won't be called
def party_list(name, age, sex):
    """
    :name:"{}" != "Dad"
    :age:17< {} <25
    :sex:True
    """
    print("You're invited to my party, {}!".format(name))


# We will make some sample data
keys = ["name", "age", "sex"]
values = [["John", 24, "Male"],
          ["Sarah", 25, "Female"],
          ["Pikachu", 2, "Pokemon"],
          ["Pizza guy", 18, "Male"]]
# Turn it in to a dictionary
for key, value in enumerate(values):
    values[key] = {t:p for t, p in zip(keys, value)}


# These conditions can be dynamically made for each function,
# because we have access to the doc string from the outside
conditions = list(filter(lambda c: ':' in c, party_list.__doc__.split('\n')))
for friend in values:
    for case in conditions:
        tag, code = case.split(':')[1:]
        if not eval(code.format(friend[tag])):
            break
    else:
        party_list(friend["name"], friend["age"], friend["sex"])
```